# How to get values from a relationship in core data (swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

I have a Entity named "Users" with 2 attributes named "username" and "password".

I have another Entity named "Info" with 4 attributes named "avatar", "level", "loss", "win".

I have a relationship setup with the "User" entity named 
"userInfo"
Destination: "Info"
Inverse: "userDetails"

I have a relationship setup with the "Info" entity named 
"userDetails"
Destination: "Users"
Inverse: "userInfo"

Here is my code right now:

```
@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // getting the inputs from the user
    let username = usernameField.text!
    let userPassword = passwordField.text!

    // creating a request to fetch the results for the users
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false



    // now getting all the results
    do
    {
        // saving results in results
        let results = try context.fetch(request)


        // now checking if there is any results
        if results.count > 0
        {
            // creating a for loop to go through the results
            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]
            {
                // checking if username and password match
                if username == (result.value(forKey: "username") as? String)! && userPassword == (result.value(forKey: "password") as? String)!
                {
                    // if they do set "isLoggedIn" to true
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey:"isLoggedIn")
                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()


                    // Now saving the username and info of the user to the main viewController to display the users data later

                    // I NEED TO SAVE FROM THE RELATIONSHIP DATA HERE

                    // dismissing this view to go to the main view
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                else
                {
                    // if username and passwords dont match then display it to the user.
                    alertMessage(userMessage: "Login failed username or password do not match!")
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // if no results then display error message
            alertMessage(userMessage: "Login Failed: No users registered!")
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // catch
    }
}
```

after checking the if the username and password are correct I need to store the data from the relationship of that username and password to 4 variables. Named: win, loss, level, and avatar.

I am confused on how to get the correct data from the relationship

I've tried using the "result" variable to try to get this but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have a pyramid of doom.  You might want to learn to use guards: https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/swift-guard-dcd725caef7e

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ project due tomorrow just need to get the data. Anyway I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

One would generally create classes that represent the entities instead of working with the entities directly as `NSManagedObjects` so that seems a little odd.  But you should be able to use setValueForKey:

```
result.setValue(/* whatever */, forKey: "userInfo.avatar")
```

Comment: I already have the values set. I'm trying to read the data and place it in a variable. Sorry if I worded the question wrong!